# The sequence $\left\{n^2f\left(\frac{1}n\right)\right\}$ is bounded where $f:\mathbb C \to \mathbb C$ is analytic

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, analytic-functions

Let $f:\mathbb C \to \mathbb C$ be an analytic function and $$\left|f\left(\frac{1}n\right)\right| \leq \frac{1}{n^{3/2}}$$ for each $n \in \mathbb N$. Now prove that the sequence $\left\{n^2f\left(\frac{1}n\right)\right\}$ is bounded.

Now notice that
$$\left| f\left(\frac{1}n\right)\right| \leq \frac{1}{n^{3/2}} \implies\left|n^2f\left(\frac{1}n\right)\right| \leq \sqrt n$$
From here how can I solve this question?

Comment: You can write $f$ as $f(z)=z^mg(z)$ where $g:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ is analytic and $g(0)\neq 0$ ($m$ is the order of the root $0$ of $f$). Then by using your hypothesis one can prove that $m\geq 2$, concluding the exercise.

Comment: Write $f$ as its Taylor series around the origin and show that the constant and the linear term must vanish due to the imposed growth condition. If those terms vanish, what is the Taylor series of $f(z)/z^2$ at the origin? Why does this imply your claim?

Answer (score 2):

It's a question about entire functions, but can be considered as a question about $C^2$ functions on a neighbourhood of $0$ in $\mathbb{R}$. Notice that the hypotheses imply $f(0) = f'(0) = 0$, so we have with l'Hospital
$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x)}{x^2} = \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{f'(x)}{2x} = \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{f''(x)}{2} = \frac{f''(0)}{2}$$